# Android java HTML Table to Hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, html-table

I am new in java. I want to read a html table and push the data into an hashmap:

Output should be:

```
row1: line1, line2, line3
row2: line1, line2, line3
```

The file only contains one table with td and tr tags and it is well formed.

How to do that?

PS: Does anybody want to translate my python code to java? ;)

Comment: No I think no one wants to translate your python code...

Comment: Ok. That was a PS. You don't havr to downvote my QUESTION

Comment: Of course I have to downvote that. you ask for code without showing your efforts: first of all read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I said i am new. I don't have an idea and i googled 2 hours. What would you do?

Comment: google  1. howto to read html/xml with java 2. Using HashMap in Java
Thats all...

Comment: Ok. The next time i will do that. But if you know that you could answer my question.

Comment: to give you a detailed answer your question is not clear enough. Contains the html page one or more tables? Is the column defined with td or th? Did you only need the value or the whole column tag? etc... 
Write that code needs some work which no one here wants to do...

Comment: Ok. I edited my question. Now you should know all.

Comment: that's not the point. You have to do the work and come back if you have a specific problem with youre "existing" java code

Comment: can you describe what you have? , because table td tr is not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TableEg extends Activity{
  Hashmap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new Hashmap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int count = 0;
    String html = "<table><tr><td>1</td><td>Some Value</td><td>Some Other Value</td><td>Yet another value</td></tr></table>";

    try {
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
     Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");
     Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");

     for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
        Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
        for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
           arrayList.add(rowItems.get(j).text());
        }
        hashMap.put(Integer.valueOf(count), arrayList);
        count++;
     }

     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try describe process in simple simple way:

1) each row will be java object, like :

```
public class Client {
String name;
int age;
...
}
```

2) You can put Client in Hashmap

```
Map <Integer, Client> myClients = new HashMap<Integer, Client>();
            myClients.put(1, new Client())
```

3) You can connect your Client object to layout

```
item.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
        x.setText("Name is " + name);
```

Comment: Map<Client> ??? Where is the key value syntax. That will never compile. Furthermore I see no mutuality between your code and the question.